# How do I reset an object's position and keep it there for a few seconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball object that is set to kinematic for the first 3 seconds of the scene so it doesn't move. `IsKinematic` is then set to false after 3 seconds using the Update function so the ball starts moving. The problem is on collision i want to 'reset' the ball back to the original position and hold it there for 3 seconds again.

I tried this on collison where i reset `timeLeft`, velocity and position. However, it resets the position but immediately drops and without stopping for 3 seconds. I dont understand why resetting the timer doesn't work. it only works when the scene is first loaded.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collisionSound != null && audioSource != null)
        {
            audioSource.clip = collisionSound;
            audioSource.Play();
        }

            // Check if the collision is with the ground
            if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") && transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            
            p2.increaseScore();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player2Score", p2.playerScore);
            timeLeft = 3.0f;
            ball.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            transform.position = originalPos;
            ball.isKinematic = true;
            pointSource.Play();


        }
        else if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") && transform.position.x > 0)
        {
            
            p1.increaseScore();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player1Score", p1.playerScore);
            timeLeft = 3.0f;
            ball.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            transform.position = originalPos;
            ball.isKinematic = true;
            pointSource.Play();


        }
    }
```

Full script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LogicScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerController p1;
    public player2controller p2;
    public AudioClip collisionSound;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioSource pointSource;
    public AudioClip pointClip;
    public bool pointScored;
    public Rigidbody2D ball;
    public float timeLeft = 3.0f;
    Vector2 originalPos;

    void Start()
    {
        originalPos = new Vector2(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y);
        p1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player1").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        p2 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player2").GetComponent<player2controller>();
        p1.playerScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player1Score", 0);
        p2.playerScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player2Score", 0);
        ball.isKinematic = true;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            ball.isKinematic = false;
        }
        else{
            ball.isKinematic = true;
        }

        if (p1.playerScore > 10 || p2.playerScore > 10)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Player1Score");
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("Player2Score");
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
            
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collisionSound != null && audioSource != null)
        {
            audioSource.clip = collisionSound;
            audioSource.Play();
        }

            // Check if the collision is with the ground
            if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") && transform.position.x < 0)
        {
            
            p2.increaseScore();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player2Score", p2.playerScore);
            timeLeft = 3.0f;
            ball.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            transform.position = originalPos;
            ball.isKinematic = true;
            pointSource.Play();


        }
        else if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground") && transform.position.x > 0)
        {
            
            p1.increaseScore();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player1Score", p1.playerScore);
            timeLeft = 3.0f;
            ball.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            transform.position = originalPos;
            ball.isKinematic = true;
            pointSource.Play();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not due to `SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);` getting called and resetting your scene? In general: [Debug your code!](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) ... if there is only this one place in your scripts where you set `ball.isKinematic = false;` then setting a break point / `Debug.Log` there should reveal pretty quick why it is called in a moment when you didn't expect it - if it actually isn't => well then either something else is doing so or as said your scene is reset (which you can also find out with a log)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a break point on the function that resets the ball & attach visual studio to unity, unity will pause when that function runs which will allow you to check the value in 'public float timeLeft' to see whats going on, you can also add a breakpoint to ball.isKinematic = false; and ball.isKinematic = true; to see what conditions the kinematic gets set under.

Comment: Well I can see in the inspector when the game is running that timeLeft does get set to 3 however the body type of the Rigidbody is never set back to kinematic. It is like the update function 'overrides' any other code.

Comment: Maybe try setting the position in the update if there is time left like GameObject.transform.position = tempPosition; to see if it is the IsKinematic or something else thats giving it issues